# Number of solutions to $n^ 2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2z^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory

I was intrigued by this result in [Journal of Number Theory](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X12002661) from 2013.  Let $n = 2^{\lambda_2}\prod p^{\lambda_p}$.

> **Theorem** The number of $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$ such that $n^ 2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2z^2$ is given by
>   $$ b(\lambda_2) \prod_p \left[ \frac{p^{\lambda_p+1}-1}{p-1} - \left( \frac{-2}{p}\right)\frac{p^{\lambda_p}-1}{p-1}  \right]$$
>   the symbol $b$ is a variant of the Legendre symbol are given by 
>   $$ b(\lambda_2) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} 1 & \lambda_2 = 0 \\
> 3 & \lambda_2 \geq 1\end{array} \right.$$
>   and the necessary values of the classical Legendre symbol are given by
>   $$ \left( \frac{-2}{p}\right) =  \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} 1 &p \equiv 1,3 \pmod 8 \\
> -1&p \equiv 5,7 \pmod 8 \end{array} \right.$$

I think this problem is slightly difficult because you have to sieve out the squares, but otherwise, shouldn't this result fall out of Hasse principle or a theta function of some kind?  I could solve this equation possibly over each prime (as well as $p=2$) and then multiply the result.

$$ p^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2z^2 $$

There's no guarantee even of one solution here, but for this enumerative result we're simply stating that we could multiply the result from all places.

Was it new to count solutions over all primes?  Does the number of solutions $r_{(1,1,2)}(p^2)$ for all primes not sufficient to determine $r_{(1,1,2)}$ in general?  I remember reading that the class number was either 1 or 2 (but I don't even know what that means).

---

There is an approach using half-integer weight forms that solved a few cases in [2014](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X14000699).

And possibly a resolution of all cases where the genus has only 1 or 2 elements in [2017](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X17302147).

Comment: This identity certainly follows from the fact that the theta series of $x^{2} + y^{2} + 2z^{2}$ is a weight $3/2$ Cohen-Eisenstein series (which follows from the fact that $x^{2} + y^{2} + 2z^{2}$ is alone in its genus). One reason the authors may have focused on representations of $n^{2}$ is that the formula for the $n$th coefficient in that case is a good bit simpler.

Comment: Right. My question is about the genera. Reading further there were a few more cases solved with weight 3/2 forms and then this year a general solution for $r(n^2)$. But only in cases where the genus has one or two elements.

Comment: From the fact $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID then $f(n) = \frac{1}{4}\# \{ x^2+y^2 =n \}$ is multiplicative $=\sum_{d | n} \chi_4(d)$ and you obtain $f(n^2)= \prod_{p^k \| n} f(p^{2k}) $ where $f(p^{2k}) = \sum_{m=0}^{2k} \chi_4(p^{2m})$. Here it is the same except it is slightly harder to show $\theta(x) \theta(y) \theta(\sqrt{2} z)$ has multiplicative coefficients (eigenfunction of Hecke operators, because it is alone [in its genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Minkowski%E2%80%93Siegel_mass_formula) ?) and an expression for them.